# UWP build different in Debug to Release

Tags: visual-studio, sockets, build, uwp, windows-runtime

I am creating a UWP application and I want to export an application package in release mode (.appx file).

In the build options of the project, the checkbox : "`Compile with native code tool string`" is a problem :

- When I **check this box**, the **installation does not end** on another computer, here is the error message:

  > The application installer was unable to install package dependencies.
  >   Ask the developer for the Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.1 package
- When the **box is unchecked**, the application **crashes** when I try to connect to a **socket**.

On the other hand, on my computer, no problems to install and use
the application (debug and release) but the use of sockets also blocks when the box is checked.

How I can make a release app for my app and another computer can install it and use socket ?

Comment: install the Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.1.appx on the 2nd PC

Comment: Thank's it's done !

Comment: @magicandre1981 Didn't quite get why should I install .net core in case of native toolchain. All required data should be shipped in native code with all required code in package. (The .NET Native toolchain will compile your managed IL binaries into native binaries.) The problem is that uwp package is missing .net core package, not that target PC does not have it.

Comment: @AccessDenied "NET Core runtime optimized for AOT (ahead of time compilation) scenarios, with the accompanying .NET native compiler toolchain. .NET Native uses CoreRT in conjunction with the UTC compiler to provide native compilation for UWP apps." so you need to install it. When you install the apps via Windows Store, the dependencies get installed automatically by the store.

Comment: The .NetCore runtime should be packaged within your appx or dropped aside. If you check your build output folder you should have your application appx package and a dependency folder containing the appx for your dependencies. You can manually install the dependencies one by one or run the deployment powershell script which will handle this for you